# Admin do Magento erro 404

Tags: php, html, css, magento

Mudei minha loja no `magento` para outro domínio, mudei as urls no banco de dados, e limpei cache, a HOME acessa normal, mas o admin esta dando erro `404`, como devo proceder?

[Loja Magento](http://rvipsuplements.com.br/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é o index.php

**http://rvipsuplements.com.br/rvip/index.php/admin**

Configure seu htaccess corretamente ou ative url retrieve no seu php.ini

**Outras coisas que podem ser**

Pode ser compilação ativada, caso seja desative ou recompile, caso admin esteja travada todas as paginas em 404 use:

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- enable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

Pode ser cache, cookies, verifica o arquivo local.xml onde contem banco e senha se o acesso a administração não mudou.

Essa esta acessando normal
http://rvipsuplements.com.br/rvip/downloader/
Pode ter ativado navegar em admin com https, ai quando entra http da 404.

Pode ter faltado '/' no fim de algum url

Comment: Por não estar pegando seu css, é provavelmente falta da ultima '/' no fim das urls, ou mapeou as urls errado.

Comment: ah cara, vou refazer, esse template ja me deu muita dor de cabeça, ta loko kkk, valew galera